# Manually adding current_page_parent to wp_list_pages()

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development, navigation, wp-list-pages

I'm using `wp_list_pages()` like so:

`<?php wp_list_pages('title_li=&include=1714'); ?>`

But would like it so that the link has a `current_page_parent` class under the following conditions:

`if (is_singular('work')) {`

Is this achievable with this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default [`wp_list_pages()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pages/) uses the [`Walker_Page`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_page/) class to create the HTML list, and there's a filter in there—[`page_css_class`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/page_css_class/)—for the CSS classes.

You should be able to do something like this:

```
/**
 * Filters the CSS classes.
 *
 * @param  array   $css_class    The current CSS classes. Array of strings.
 * @param  WP_Post $page         The current page object.
 * @param  int     $depth        Depth of the page.
 * @param  array   $args         Array of arguments.
 * @param  int     $current_page ID of the current page.
 * @return array                 The filtered array of classes.
 */
function wpse_378686_page_classes( $css_class, $page, $depth, $args, $current_page ) {
    if ( is_singular( 'work' ) && 1703 == $page->ID ) {
        $css_class[] = 'current_page_parent';
    }
    return $css_class;
}
add_filter( 'page_css_class', 'wpse_378686_page_classes', 10, 5 );
```

Add that code snippet to your active theme's `functions.php` file, or to a plugin that you would then activate.

### Notes

- `is_singular( 'work' )` should be `true` on any single `work` custom post.
- I've changed the code to use `$page->ID` instead of `$current_page`, as I think the `$page` variable contains the page that the page list is currently processing.

(Edited to reflect the comment re: page ID 1714. Edited again after clarification in the comments (and a change to page ID 1703 instead of 1714).)

Comment: thank you! although I should have been more specific sorry, I would like it so that it only applies to page 1714 and no others... as I am using the `wp_list_pages` function elsewhere in my theme for other pages

Comment: Since `$current_page` is passed to the filter, you can easily check to make sure you're on page 1714 as well. (I've updated my code to do this, assuming that `1714` is the page's ID and not the title.)

Comment: thanks again! I'm actually trying to do it with a different page now like so `if ( is_singular( 'work' ) && 1703 == $current_page` — but it only seems to be applying the `current_page_parent` class to page `1714` list item! do I need to change the ID somewhere else too?

Comment: ...correction, it's applying the class to my posts page in the nav (which is ID 1711)

Comment: Do you want the class to appear only on the nav menu item with ID 1714 (or 1703), or only when you're looking at the menu as it's presented on page 1714|1703?

Comment: I'd just like it so that it appears on the nav item (1703) when a 'work' custom post is being viewed... not so much when page 1703 is being viewed itself

Comment: I've added the following line to try and debug it `$css_class[] = 'test-' . $current_page;` and each item in the list is being output as `test-0` — e.g. see how the class of 1703 looks here `page_item page-item-1703 test-0`

Comment: Check the updated version of the code. I've switched to using `$page->ID` because that should reflect the item being processed in the list of pages.

Comment: thank you! the 1703 link now has the class applied to it :D but I'm finding that the posts page (1711) still has the `current_page_parent` class... is this easy enough to remove?